# Как отправить данные qr_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, qr

Всем привет, мне нужно генерировать qr код из данных, которые мне приходят с сервера... Но есть проблема, как я вычитал, qr_flutter как данные принимает только строку, но ладно, это еще не проблема, можно попросить бекендера попросить возвращать мне онли строки. Но, как мне быть с тем, что мне нужно за раз отправлять в этот qr код несколько данных - вот пример, как он выглядит сейчас

```
 QrImage(
         data: "1234567890", 
         version: QrVersions.auto,
         size: 300.0,
            ),
```

Учитывая, что он принимает, только строки, не объект и не массив, как мне быть?

А вот, что мне приходит с сервера - `{"PaymentSysName":"PaymentSys","MerchantId":40075,"MerchantName":"Merchant40075","Amount":10.0,"CashierId":50053}`

Собственно, суть вопроса. Как мне запихнуть эти данные в `QrImage(data: ???)`

Answer (score 0):

```
String? text = '';

@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    setState(() {
      text = await fetchData();
    });
  }
}

Future<String?> fetchData() {
// Тут надо с сервера загрузить данные
}

...

QrImage(
  data = text != null ? text! : 'null'
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я получаю ошибку - **The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'Qr'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.**


И -------------------------------------------------------- 
**The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<String>', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)  Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.**
Вот, как выглядит мой код [https://dpaste.org/AV2it]

Comment: Daniil Исправил код. Сделал, чтобы можно было получать нулевые значения и проверяю по итогу нулевое оно или нет. А метод setState существует только в StatefulWidget. Если у вас StatelessWidget, то можно использовать StatefulBuilder (в него нужно упаковать QrImage). Однако, рекомендую делать эту страницу StatefulWidget